# Set environment variable in Visual Studio Code debugger on a Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I want to use the VSCode debugger and want to set the environment variables before launching the app. The configuration in the Launch folder looks something like this.

```
    {
        "name": "Launch on iOS",
        "type": "nativescript",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios",
        "appRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "watch": true,
        "environment": [
            {
                "BUILD_ENV": "local"
            }
        ]
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work though. I am using a Mac.

[image: Problem reported by VSCode]

Comment: You mean the webpack environment variables? Have you defined `BUILD_ENV` in your `webpack.config.js`? If yes, then try adding `"tnsArgs":["--bundle", "--env.BUILD_ENV=local"]`.

Comment: doesn't seem to pick up the value of the variable

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works:

```
"env": {
  "BUILD_ENV": "local"
}
```

or

```
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

or

```
"osx": {
    "environment": [
       {  "name": "", 
          "value": ""
      }
   ]
},
```

See [platform-specific properties](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_platformspecific-properties).

Comment: env isn't recognized either. I dont have separate env file. The variable is defined in the package.json

Comment: So just typing "env" does that bring up any intellisense for a likely environment variable?  I get both of the above options.

Comment: I also just found the "osx" option above as well from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971572/how-do-i-add-environment-variables-to-launch-json-in-vscode [upvote the last answer.]

Comment: Tried this

"osx": {
    "environment": [
        {
            "name": "BUILD_ENV",
            "value": "local"
        },
        {
            "BUILD_ENV": "local"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: this

"osx": {
    "env": [
        {
            "name": "BUILD_ENV",
            "value": "local"
        },
        {
            "BUILD_ENV": "local"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: this

"osx": {
    "BUILD_ENV": "local"
}

Nothing worked