# How do I use custom environment variables in launch.json in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I know this question might sound similar to this one: [How do I add environment variables to launch.json in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971572/how-do-i-add-environment-variables-to-launch-json-in-vscode)

But what I really want is to use the variables from my .env file inside the actual launch.json file, instead of using them in the program.

So my setup is something like this:

```
project-root/
  |-- .env
  |-- .vscode/
        |-- launch.json
  |-- src/
        |-- my-plugin/
        |-- my-theme/
  |-- wordpress/
  |-- data/
  |-- docker-compose.yml
```

In my .env file I have this:

```
PLUGIN_SLUG=my-plugin
THEME_SLUG=my-theme
```

Now, in my launch.json file, I would really like to be able to use the `${THEME_SLUG}` and `${PLUGIN_SLUG}` variables like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/${PLUGIN_SLUG}": "${workspaceRoot}/src/${PLUGIN_SLUG}",
        "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/${THEME_SLUG}": "${workspaceRoot}/src/${THEME_SLUG}",
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/wordpress",
      },
    }
  ],
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

::EDIT::

After digging some further, I realized that when I set the variables globally inside `/etc/profile.d/temp.sh` like this:

```
export PLUGIN_SLUG=codeable-plugin
export THEME_SLUG=codeable-theme
```

After logging out of my system and back in, I'm able to use these variables anywhere, including in my launch.json file like this:

```
   "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/${env:PLUGIN_SLUG}": "${workspaceRoot}/src/${env:PLUGIN_SLUG}",
   "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/${env:THEME_SLUG}": "${workspaceRoot}/src/${env:THEME_SLUG}",
```

While this is a step closer to what I want, it's not really workable, to update these variables manually in my global OS config each time I switch projects, and then log out and in again.

Comment: What extension are you using? `php` is not a valid type for launch configs. Ultimately, I think you will be at the mercy of extension support on this one sadly. I think your question is specific to php and using an `.env` file not just 'using custom env variables', because, for example, using `envFile` is already supported with node launch configs

Comment: @soulshined PHP Debug by Felix Becker. Do you have any reference to how it could be done for a simple node launch config? (without PHP)

Comment: Sure. You just use the built in node configurations and call the `envFile` property, enter the file name and to reference the variables you do it like you showed in your example:`${env:}`

Comment: I'm sure I tried this with a default node project and I'm pretty sure VSC does not load the .env file automatically. I believe `${env:}` is only available for global system variables. I could be wrong though. Did you find any documentation about this?

Comment: It does not load an `.env` file automatically, correct. That’s what the `envFile` property is for. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/master/OPTIONS.md

Comment: Thanks, just found the docs about this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_load-environment-variables-from-external-file-node. Would be cool if this was supported by the PHP extension as well.. I'll see where I can create an issue for this :)