# Why when i debug node app with vscode Run and debug, process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined?

Tags: environment-variables, dotenv

I have set **export NODE_ENV=development** already.

script.js

```js
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV;
console.log(nodeEnv);
```

1.) when script is started with `node script` command, nodeEnv variable is assign to value **'development'**

2.) however when script is started with **Run and debug** (vscode) variable is **undefined**

Why are those results different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem some weeks ago. I use Linux, but there is already a question similar to this one. [Answers to this question helped me to resolve my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971572/how-do-i-add-environment-variables-to-launch-json-in-vscode)

Adding **"env": { "NODE_ENV": "development" }** to vscode laucher.json config might do the trick.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your quick answer, this config has fixed it !

Comment: Cheers Boss. Happy Coding!!