# Visual Studio Code - Cannot set env without running a program (or

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I am been shown this unusual error. It has just started appearing and it's preventing me from debugging my WSL web solution.

I am running a php wordpress site in Visual Studio code and debugging it using XDebug. I have the following in my `launch.json` which I know for a fact worked yesterday and has been working fine for a while now.

When I try and debug I get a pop saying the following

[image: pop up]

I've never seen this message before and I can't see any information online about it.

My launch.json looks like the following

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name":"Listen for XDebug",
        "type":"php",
        "request":"launch",
        "port":9003,
        "pathMappings": {
            "server path": "${workspaceRoot}" 
        },
        "xdebugSettings": {
            "max_data": 10000,
            //"show_hidden": 1,
            "max_children": 250,
            "max_depth": 10
        },
        "env": {
            "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug",
            "XDEBUG_TRIGGER": "VSCODE"
        }
    }
]
```

'server path' is the path of the project on the server.

I first thought that maybe the port was being used by something elese but it wasn't.

I have tried restarting Apache2, reloading PHP7.3-fpm and turning my computer off in the hopes that the issue resolves itself yet nothing seems to be working.

Has anyone else came across this issue?

Comment: could you please try `"environment"` instead of `"env"`?

Comment: @GrafiCode That's it! Why is that the case all of a sudden? `env` has been fine up until now?

Comment: please check out the second comment to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426595/5334486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that all of a sudden, for some reason `env` was not recognised and VSC no longer liked it. Replacing it with `enivornment` (as per the comment GrafiCode suggested) in the `launch.json` fixed the issue.

According to @burito in the comment, `env` has been renamed to `environment.

My only guess as to why this happened is that I have a `.env` file in my root that could had of been overriding the launch and so when I launched the solution, it hit the `.env` file first and seen that the solution wasn't running...thereby throwing the error/ pop-up.

Comment: Hi. `env` was not renamed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71856274/1627618

Answer (score 4):

1. [Open plugins and click gear icon for "PHP Debug" Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka5Tb.png)
2. From dropdown menu, select "Install Another Version"
3. [Click to select "1.25.0" from the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8bAW.png)
4. [Click "Reload Required" to restart VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfDIj.png)

Answer (score 1):

php-debug dev here.

I have added this error because people don't understand that without starting a program/script the debug adapter cannot influence the environment Xdebug is running in. Effectively in your launch.json the `env` does nothing.

Looking back on the change, I should have introduced a warning first...

Just to clarify, `env` was NOT renamed to `enivornment`.

Comment: Can you think of any reason as to why this would have all of a sudden happened? Even though nothing in the solution had changed from working to breaking? Also, is there any reason that the error stops at `(or`

Comment: I implemented and released this yesterday. See this PR https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/pull/777
The text got somehow cut off and I did not see this. I will release a fix,

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the browser extension "**Xdebug helper**".
If set to "debug" it sets a cookie with "XDEBUG_TRIGGER: true" which triggers the debugging when you have `start_with_request=trigger` in php.ini.

(it's also possible to add the query parameter `?XDEBUG_TRIGGER=1` to the url).